# How common is it for hornets to drop stingers

Tags: terraria-console

How common is the stinger drop? I really want the Thorn Chakram for a Skeletron battle.

Answer (score 1):

Drop rate of "Stinger" from Hornets and Spiked Jungle Slimes :

- 66% in normal mode
- 100% in expert mode

[Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stinger)

Comment: Thnx I may now have a chance with your help.

Comment: That said, there's no Expert Mode in the console version.

Comment: True, but people could search the same thing for a pc version.